# ChartJs(Java) Can I remove only specific gridLines for a Linear Chart withouth removing the labels on xAxis?

Tags: java, charts, chart.js, vaadin

I have the following problem with com.byteowls.vaadin.chartjs ChartJs - I do not know how to remove gridLines conditionally without removing the labels.  Here is the following code I have for creating the ChartJs :
`

```
BarChartOptions options = barChartConfig.options();
        options.title().text(title).display(true);
        options.legend().position(Position.RIGHT);
        options.tooltips().mode(InteractionMode.X);
        options.legend().labels().boxWidth(10).fontSize(10);
        options.tooltips().position(Tooltips.PositionMode.NEAREST);

    LinearScale yScale = new LinearScale();
    yScale.stacked(true);
    yScale.ticks().beginAtZero(true);
    options.scales().add(Axis.Y, yScale);
    DefaultScale xScale = new DefaultScale();
    xScale.stacked(true);

    xScale.ticks().autoSkip(false).callback("function(value,index,values){\n" +
            "if(index % 2 !== 0){\n" +
            "    return undefined;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "} \n" +
            "return value;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "}");
    xScale.gridLines().lineWidth(1).color("rgb(0,0,0)");
    options.scales().add(Axis.X, xScale);

    ChartJs horizontalStackedChart = new ChartJs(barChartConfig);
    horizontalStackedChart.setHeight(70, Sizeable.Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    horizontalStackedChart.setWidthFull();
    return horizontalStackedChart;`
```

and here is the Image: [Chart Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxgiw.png)

And there is the image I want to happen but with the labels from the previous chart: [Chart Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAsd4.png)

After i found on internet that there is a callback functions for the ticks are tried many ways but no one helps. I want to show gridLines after two datasets how it looks like in 'Chart Image 2' but the labels are gone. And I do not understand why this is happening. Is it possible actually?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the lineColor of your xAxis gridLines to a function where you set the desired lines that you want to remove to a fully opague collor.

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          color: (ctx) => (ctx.index % 2 === 0 ? 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' : 'red')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you know where i can do that function in Java? Because I've tried inside the xScale.ticks().gridLines().color(ctx) => (ctx.index % 2 === 0 ? 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' : 'red') but nothing happened.

Comment: No, dont have nay knowledge if the java wrapper supports it, also it seems like you are using v2 of the lib from the naming of your options, dont know if v2 supports grid color as a scriptable option so you might need to update to v3

Comment: What do you mean under version 2 or version 3. Is that a version for the ChartJs library? Because the latest version I found in maven repository is 1.4.0.

Comment: Yes, it is, chart.js is a js lib so someone build a java wrapper around it so you need to make sure you are using the wrapper that uses chart.js v3 as a basis

Comment: Hey i'm sorry but maybe mistake is mine I've edited the question now because maybe there is another library which is called ChartJs. I've used this library for Vaadin 8.0 here is the import 'com.byteowls.vaadin.chartjs' and maybe 1.4.0 is the latest for Vaadin 8.0.

Comment: Like I said its a wrapper in java around the chart.js lib which is a js lib, in the readme of your java package you can see he links to the base js lib so you will need to put in an issue if he is ever going to update his wrapper or switch to another java wrapper/lib